# How to access a map defined in another component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, nuxt.js

I'm currently using a Leaflet map (with vue2leaflet).

What I do is pretty much standard:

- A list of places is imported from a REST Api in the app store (vuex)
- Then on the map initialization, the markers are generated using these informations in the store

So basically my **Map.vue** calls the map:

```
<v-map ref="map" :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
    <v-tilelayer url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"></v-tilelayer>
    <v-marker-cluster :options="clusterOptions">
        <v-marker v-for="(marker, index) in markers"
            :key="index"
            :lat-lng="makeCoords(marker.location.lat, marker.location.lng)"
                v-on:l-click="showSpot(marker._id, marker.slug, marker.location.lat, marker.location.lng)">
        </v-marker>
    </v-marker-cluster>
</v-map>
```

**Markers** is coming from the store ($store.map.markers):

```
computed: {
    markers () {
        return this.$store.state.map.markers
    }
}
```

So in the same Template, if I want to get a reference to the map, I just need to do this:

```
this.$refs.map
```

But I would need to do the same from another file (let's say "**AddMarker.vue**", in order to place new markers on the map, using this method:

```
L.marker([datas.location.lat, datas.location.lng]).addTo(mymap);
```

where "mymap" should be the  object defined in **Map.vue**

Of course, as the map is not in the same file, **this.$refs.map** results in "undefined".

I tried to add the map reference in the store, but it's not working and fires an error (call stack), I guess it's not made to store components.

I tried to just commit the new marker in the store, but the map won't just magically adapt and add it. I guess I really need to call the addTo() method for this.

Here's the store:

```
export const state = () => ({
    markers: null
})

export const mutations = {
    setMarkers(state, markers) {
        state.markers = markers
    },

    addMarker(state, marker) {
        state.markers.push(marker)
    }
}

export const actions = {
    async init({ commit }) {
        let { data } = await this.$axios.get(process.env.api.spots)
        commit('setMarkers', data)
    }
}
```

And here's how I call the mutation:

```
    that.$store.commit('map/addMarker', {
            title: values.title,
            description: values.description,
            location: {
                city: that.$store.state.position.infos.city,
                country: that.$store.state.position.infos.country,
                lat: that.$store.state.position.coords.lat,
                lng: that.$store.state.position.coords.lng
            }
        });
```

The marker is perfectly added in the store, yet nothing happen on the map.

If anyone know how to deal with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Where is `markers` populated from? The store?

Comment: Using an [event bus](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/) might not be a bad idea, kinda redundant though on top of the store.

Comment: @RoyJ -> Yes, it's a simple array containing all markers informations as objects.

Comment: @btl Mmmh, I wasn't aware of this… Might come in handy, thanks! But why do you think it would be redundant with the store? They're not meant to do the same stuff, aren't they?

Comment: You can achieve the same effect using either or. I often find having a persisted state beneficial, plus the `map` helper functions cut out a lot of code.

Comment: Have you tried using `splice` instead of `push` in the mutation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual problem is: "how do I add another marker to `markers`?" If you define `markers` as a computed that is based on the store, then it's a matter of adding a marker to the store.

```js
Vue.component('v-map', Vue2Leaflet.Map);
Vue.component('v-tilelayer', Vue2Leaflet.TileLayer);
Vue.component('v-marker', Vue2Leaflet.Marker);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    markers: [
      [47.42, -1.25],
      [47.41, -1.21],
      [47.43, -1.22]
    ].map(p => L.latLng(...p))
  },
  mutations: {
    addMarker(state, payload) {
      state.markers.push(payload);
    }
  },
  actions: {
    addMarker({
      commit
    }, payload) {
      commit('addMarker', payload)
    }
  }
})

const v = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: 13,
      center: [47.413220, -1.219482],
      url: 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    markers() {
      return this.$store.state.markers;
    }
  }
});

setTimeout(() => {
  store.dispatch('addMarker', L.latLng(47.412, -1.24));
}, 1400);
```

```css
html,
body,
#app {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue2-leaflet@0.0.57/dist/vue2-leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vuex@latest/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<link href="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app">
  <v-map :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
    <v-tilelayer :url="url" :attribution="attribution"></v-tilelayer>
    <v-marker v-for="marker in markers" :lat-lng="marker"></v-marker>
  </v-map>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not really it. I already know how to add a marker to "markers" in the store. But as I said, it won't do the trick, as the map won't just reinitialize itself to show the new marker. But I see you're adding the store directly in the vue file… Is it for this purpose?

Comment: You haven't defined `markers` as a computed based on the store.

Comment: In fact, yes I have. I might add it in the original post. Edit: it's done.

Comment: You can see that it works in my example. There is something wrong with the process of adding it to your store. The map will update if the array of markers changes.

Comment: I can see that… I wondered if it could be because of this ".map(p => L.latLng(...p))" you added to the markers array, but I tried without in a fiddle and it works the same.

But I can't see what's the big difference between this one and the way I do it. I'll add this too in the post.

Edit: okay, I added the store part in the original post.

Comment: Be sure that what you are adding to the store is in the same format as what is in the store.

Comment: My bad, it was coming from totally another thing, but it was adding a false information in the store, and not firing any error… But it works indeed! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an event bus for this situation; you've got components that can add markers on a map, say a list of addresses and when you click one a pin drops to it's location.

```
// bus.js
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();

// address-list.js
import { EventBus } from './bus.js';

methods: {
   onClick () {
      EventBus.$emit('add-marker', {x:123,y:345});
   }
}

// map.js
import { EventBus } from './bus.js';

EventBus.$on('add-marker', coords => {
   this.addMarker(coords).then(() => this.redrawMap())
});
```

Straightforward, not a lot of code. Being a global bus, obviously you can re-use in any component necessary.

Comment: That's what I tried after I saw your previous comment; and it works well, but still don't do the trick, for a reason I don't get. But your "redrawMap()" gave me the idea of looking at the redraw() method of Leaflet, which can be a part of what I miss. By the way, I found this about a simpler way to use EventBus: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/849#issuecomment-307016399

Comment: I'm not familiar with leaflet so I just assumed there was a redraw or update method in play somewhere. Google maps needs it's tile layers updated in different situations. And as for the root element as the event hub, I'm not sure that this.$root is always the same when nesting several components deep. I've ran into some issues with it while integrating UI libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!